# What should I do if my university accepted too many first year grad students and now not everyone can find a pi/permanent lab?

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school, administration

The university accepted way too many students and now about 25% of the cohort is having to do additional rotations because it seems like the school does not have enough PIs or mentors to take on everyone. How can I warn new and incoming/applying students about the dangers/mismanagement of the program?

Comment: Well, it seems unlikely they will accept many students next time around. It also seems unlikely that they _planned_ to do this. The yield (percent accepting an offer of admissions) can vary year-to-year, sometimes dramatically, through no fault of the students or the department. So they will deal with it and they seem to be doing so. This is not "mismanagement". Would you prefer that they turned away admitted students once the program was "full" back in the spring?

Comment: in what position are you? A professor? A PhD student? What you CAN do heavily depends on the channels and means you have access to

Comment: im a 1st year graduate student - All the TA positions are filled and there is a waitlist. I would like to show the administration how other universities have handled this - such as UCSD releasing more funds to support the students who cannot join labs due to financial constraints, but that type of information is usually in house and hard to find.

Answer (score 7):

Strange question. Why should you do anything?

Your department likely went on historical return rates on positions offered vs accepted and ended up with WAY more than anticipated. Sometimes these things happen. The other end of it is unprecedentedly low acceptance of offers which greatly understaffs the department for TA and research needs. Also not good.

Why would it matter for next application cycle? One would assume the department will look at the number of positions available, taking into account the large cohort from the prior cycle, adjust for their past acceptance rate and act accordingly.